# How to join Pyspark dataframes based on groups

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have 2 Pyspark dataframes

Dataframe 1 - `df` where the columns are `customer_id, address_id, order_id, date the order was placed, order_share`

```
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+
|c_id|a_id|order_id|order_date|order_share|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+
|  c1|  a1|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|
|  c1|  a2|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|
|  c1|  a3|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|
|  c2|  a5|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|
|  c2|  a6|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|
|  c1|  a1|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a2|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a3|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Dataframe 2 - `df_address` where the columns are `customer_id, address_id, the date of address creation`

```
+----+----+------------+
|c_id|a_id|created_date|
+----+----+------------+
|  c1|  a1|  2020-12-31|
|  c1|  a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c1|  a4|  2020-01-16|
|  c2|  a5|  2020-12-28|
|  c2|  a6|  2020-05-16|
|  c2|  a7|  2020-03-04|
+----+----+------------+
```

Now, I wish to join both these tables such that for **every order_id**, I get the address from `df_address` and the corresponding entry should be `0.0` in the `order_share` column

My output should look like

```
+----+----+------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|c_id|a_id|created_date|order_id|order_date|order_share|
+----+----+------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|  c1|  a1|  2020-12-31|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|
|  c1|  a2|  2020-04-23|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|
|  c1|  a3|  2020-03-23|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|
|  c1|  a4|  2020-01-16|       1|2021-01-23|        0.0|
|  c2|  a5|  2020-12-28|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|
|  c2|  a6|  2020-05-16|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|
|  c2|  a7|  2020-03-04|       2|2021-03-20|        0.0|
|  c1|  a1|  2020-12-31|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a2|  2020-04-23|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a3|  2020-03-23|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4|
|  c1|  a4|  2020-01-16|       3|2021-02-20|        0.0|
+----+----+------------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

This doesn't look like a normal left/right join and I should do this for every order_id.

I tried joining using `['c_id','a_id']` but the output is no where close to expected. Considering `df_address` as left and `df` as right, Using `left join` gives me null values for `order_id` and `right join` doesn't give me all the addresses from `df_address`

It looks like I have to apply some sort of groupby for every order_id and then apply the join for each group, but I don't know how to implement this or even sure if that's the right way to go about it

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: whats stopping you to do a `left` join on `c_id` and `a_id`

Comment: Please check the edit to the question, I have stated the problem I am facing while using left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a intermediate `orders` dataframe, created from `df` dataframe and that contains only information about orders, which are columns `customer_id`, `order_id` and `order_date`. Then you first inner join `df_address` dataframe with this `orders` dataframe, to link each couple `(customer_id, address_id)` to orders-specific information, and then left join the resulting dataframe with `df` dataframe to get `order_share` per address, then replace `null` value in `order_share` column with `0.0`.

Here is the complete code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Orders dataframe that contains only orders-specific information
orders = df.select('customer_id', 'order_id', 'order_date').distinct()

df_address.join(orders, ['customer_id']) \ # link addresses with orders
  .join(df.drop('order_date'), ['customer_id', 'address_id', 'order_id'], 'left_outer') \ # link orders/addresses with order shares
  .withColumn('order_share', F.when(F.col('order_share').isNotNull(), F.col('order_share')).otherwise(F.lit(0.0))) \ # replace null in order_share column with 0.0
  .orderBy('customer_id', 'order_id', 'address_id') \ # optional, to reorder dataframe
```

#### Details

*Note: I reordered all dataframes here by `order_id` and `address_id` for readability purpose*

Starting from `df` dataframe in your question, we get the following `orders` dataframe:

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
|customer_id|order_id|order_date|
+-----------+--------+----------+
|c1         |1       |2021-01-23|
|c2         |2       |2021-03-20|
|c1         |3       |2021-02-20|
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

Then we join this `orders` dataframe with the `df_address` dataframe:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+--------+----------+
|customer_id|address_id|created_date|order_id|order_date|
+-----------+----------+------------+--------+----------+
|c1         |a1        |2020-12-31  |1       |2021-01-23|
|c1         |a2        |2020-04-23  |1       |2021-01-23|
|c1         |a3        |2020-03-23  |1       |2021-01-23|
|c1         |a4        |2020-01-16  |1       |2021-01-23|
|c2         |a5        |2020-12-28  |2       |2021-03-20|
|c2         |a6        |2020-05-16  |2       |2021-03-20|
|c2         |a7        |2020-03-04  |2       |2021-03-20|
|c1         |a1        |2020-12-31  |3       |2021-02-20|
|c1         |a2        |2020-04-23  |3       |2021-02-20|
|c1         |a3        |2020-03-23  |3       |2021-02-20|
|c1         |a4        |2020-01-16  |3       |2021-02-20|
+-----------+----------+------------+--------+----------+
```

And with a last join with `df` dataframe without column `order_date`, we get:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|customer_id|address_id|order_id|created_date|order_date|order_share|
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|c1         |a1        |1       |2020-12-31  |2021-01-23|0.5        |
|c1         |a2        |1       |2020-04-23  |2021-01-23|0.2        |
|c1         |a3        |1       |2020-03-23  |2021-01-23|0.3        |
|c1         |a4        |1       |2020-01-16  |2021-01-23|null       |
|c2         |a5        |2       |2020-12-28  |2021-03-20|0.4        |
|c2         |a6        |2       |2020-05-16  |2021-03-20|0.6        |
|c2         |a7        |2       |2020-03-04  |2021-03-20|null       |
|c1         |a1        |3       |2020-12-31  |2021-02-20|0.3        |
|c1         |a2        |3       |2020-04-23  |2021-02-20|0.3        |
|c1         |a3        |3       |2020-03-23  |2021-02-20|0.4        |
|c1         |a4        |3       |2020-01-16  |2021-02-20|null       |
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

We then just have to replace `null` with `0.0` and we get our expected dataframe:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|customer_id|address_id|order_id|created_date|order_date|order_share|
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
|         c1|        a1|       1|  2020-12-31|2021-01-23|        0.5|
|         c1|        a2|       1|  2020-04-23|2021-01-23|        0.2|
|         c1|        a3|       1|  2020-03-23|2021-01-23|        0.3|
|         c1|        a4|       1|  2020-01-16|2021-01-23|        0.0|
|         c2|        a5|       2|  2020-12-28|2021-03-20|        0.4|
|         c2|        a6|       2|  2020-05-16|2021-03-20|        0.6|
|         c2|        a7|       2|  2020-03-04|2021-03-20|        0.0|
|         c1|        a1|       3|  2020-12-31|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|         c1|        a2|       3|  2020-04-23|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|         c1|        a3|       3|  2020-03-23|2021-02-20|        0.4|
|         c1|        a4|       3|  2020-01-16|2021-02-20|        0.0|
+-----------+----------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a few clarifications, I don't think `distinct` is really needed while creating `orders` as the row is always going to be unique? And also, using `left_outer` or `left` mean the same thing while joining right?

Comment: About useless `distinct`, rows with only `customer_id`, `order_id` and `order_date` will not be unique because we removed columns `address_id` and `order_share`. With your example `df` dataframe, if you remove `distinct`, in `orders` dataframe you will get three times `(c1, 1, 2021-01-23)` row, two times `(c2, 2, 2021-03-20)` row and three times `(c1, 3, 2021-02-20)` row. So you have to keep `distinct`. And yes, `left_outer` and `left` means the same thing when joining two dataframes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had something else in mind. I understand the use of `distinct`. I Just to clarify, we use `distinct` interchangeably with `dropDuplicates` right?

Comment: Yes, you can use `distinct` and `dropDuplicates` without argument interchangeably here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a `full outer` join with the `DataFrames` to get the missing `c_id` and `a_id` combination & further utilising **when** with **isNull** for `Null` column values coming from `df` and replacing when them values from `df_address` below are the results -

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str1 = """
c1|  a1|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|
c1|  a2|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|
c1|  a3|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|
c2|  a5|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|
c2|  a6|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|
c1|  a1|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
c1|  a2|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
c1|  a3|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4
""".split("|")

input_values1 = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, input_str1))

cols1 = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, "c_id|a_id|order_id|order_date|order_share".split("|")))
            
n = len(input_values1)
n_col1 = 5

input_list1 = [tuple(input_values1[i:i+n_col1]) for i in range(0,n,n_col1)]

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list1, cols1)

sparkDF1.show()

+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+
|c_id|a_id|order_id|order_date|order_share|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+
|  c1|  a1|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|
|  c1|  a2|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|
|  c1|  a3|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|
|  c2|  a5|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|
|  c2|  a6|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|
|  c1|  a1|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a2|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|
|  c1|  a3|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+

input_str2 = """
c1|  a1|  2020-12-31|
c1|  a2|  2020-04-23|
c1|  a3|  2020-03-23|
c1|  a4|  2020-01-16|
c2|  a5|  2020-12-28|
c2|  a6|  2020-05-16|
c2|  a7|  2020-03-04
""".split("|")

input_values2 = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, input_str2))

cols2 = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != '' else None, "c_id|a_id|created_date".split("|")))
            
n = len(input_values2)
n_col2 = 3

input_list2 = [tuple(input_values2[i:i+n_col2]) for i in range(0,n,n_col2)]

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(input_list2, cols2)

sparkDF2.show()

+----+----+------------+
|c_id|a_id|created_date|
+----+----+------------+
|  c1|  a1|  2020-12-31|
|  c1|  a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c1|  a4|  2020-01-16|
|  c2|  a5|  2020-12-28|
|  c2|  a6|  2020-05-16|
|  c2|  a7|  2020-03-04|
+----+----+------------+
```

#### Full Join

Renaming Column values coming from SparkDF2 , which will be further used to populate null values to avoid ambiguous column names

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                       , (sparkDF1['c_id'] == sparkDF2['c_id'])
                        & (sparkDF1['a_id'] == sparkDF2['a_id'])
                        ,'full'
                ).select(sparkDF1['*']
                         ,sparkDF2['c_id'].alias('c_id_address')
                         ,sparkDF2['a_id'].alias('a_id_address')
                         ,sparkDF2['created_date']
                        )
finalDF.show()

+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|c_id|a_id|order_id|order_date|order_share|c_id_address|a_id_address|created_date|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|  c1|  a3|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|          c1|          a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c1|  a3|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4|          c1|          a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c2|  a5|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|          c2|          a5|  2020-12-28|
|null|null|    null|      null|       null|          c2|          a7|  2020-03-04|
|  c1|  a2|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|          c1|          a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a2|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|          c1|          a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a1|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|          c1|          a1|  2020-12-31|
|  c1|  a1|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|          c1|          a1|  2020-12-31|
|null|null|    null|      null|       null|          c1|          a4|  2020-01-16|
|  c2|  a6|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|          c2|          a6|  2020-05-16|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

#### When isNull

```
finalDF = finalDF.withColumn('c_id',F.when(F.col('c_id').isNull()
                                           ,F.col('c_id_address')).otherwise(F.col('c_id'))
                            )\
                    .withColumn('a_id',F.when(F.col('a_id').isNull()
                                              ,F.col('a_id_address')).otherwise(F.col('a_id'))
                            )\
                    .withColumn('order_share',F.when(F.col('order_share').isNull()
                                                     ,0.0).otherwise(F.col('order_share'))
                            )


finalDF.show()

+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|c_id|a_id|order_id|order_date|order_share|c_id_address|a_id_address|created_date|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|  c1|  a3|       1|2021-01-23|        0.3|          c1|          a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c1|  a3|       3|2021-02-20|        0.4|          c1|          a3|  2020-03-23|
|  c2|  a5|       2|2021-03-20|        0.4|          c2|          a5|  2020-12-28|
|  c2|  a7|    null|      null|        0.0|          c2|          a7|  2020-03-04|
|  c1|  a2|       1|2021-01-23|        0.2|          c1|          a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a2|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|          c1|          a2|  2020-04-23|
|  c1|  a1|       1|2021-01-23|        0.5|          c1|          a1|  2020-12-31|
|  c1|  a1|       3|2021-02-20|        0.3|          c1|          a1|  2020-12-31|
|  c1|  a4|    null|      null|        0.0|          c1|          a4|  2020-01-16|
|  c2|  a6|       2|2021-03-20|        0.6|          c2|          a6|  2020-05-16|
+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**Note - `order_id` and `order_date` are null as there is not value present in for the `c_id` and `a_id` combination in `sparkDF2`**

This example is provide a approach , towards getting your required solution , you can further improvise if required to populate the order missing values